# sqlite date format for android

Tags: android, sqlite, simpledateformat

I have a table in **SQLITE** with a `DATETIME` column.
I do a SQL statement which populates it with now()

I want to retreive it and parse it as a Date object in java, with following code:

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat
("yyyy-MM-ddHH:mm:ss",Locale.ENGLISH);
simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

then I get the date via:

```
Date d = simpleDateFormat.parse
(recordset.getString(recordset.getColumnIndex("storedate")));
```

I get parse exception: unparceable date (and I guess it has to do with the format. Anyone can tell me which format it should be or where the error is?

Comment: what format are you saving the date or what does this statement return ? recordset.getString(recordset.getColumnIndex("storedate")) ;

Comment: What is the rest of that warning: "Unparseable date: ..."?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what it was. I had to change the format to this one:

```
"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy"
```

now it works. Guess SQLite is storing datetime objects in this format by default.

Comment: It may have worked, but its not the norm at all : http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html See section `Time Strings`

Comment: I saw that page. saw there was a 'now' function, which I decided to use. If you say it's not the norm, then what is?

Comment: Using 1 2 or 3, depending on whether you need just date, datetime, or datetime with seconds. Any are valid, but 3 would be better suited for you? Its also easier readable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
simpleDateFormat.format(
  new Date(
    recordset.getString(
      recordset.getColumnIndex("storedate")
)));
```

Comment: Please provide some more detail. Tell us _why_ that's a good idea.